PDF with multiple HTML div elements on separate pages using JSPdf angular?
I tried the below code only first div content and the Description text on second page print second div content is not getting printed
const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
    const element = document.getElementById('div1');
    const element2 = document.getElementById('div2');
doc.html(element, {
            callback: function (doc) {
             
              resolve();
            },
            margin: [8,8,8,8],
            x: 3,
            y: 3
          });
        });

doc.addpage();
doc.text("Description = " ,15,20);
doc.html(element2, {
            callback: function (doc) {
             
              resolve();
            },
            margin: [8,8,8,8],
            x: 3,
            y: 3
          });

        });
  doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');  
```  I tried with autotable but autotable can't take div content


Have you found a solution for it? I'm also facing the same problem.
